# How to write a string in reverse word by word?

Tags: python

How to write a string in reverse
ex : My name is VicTus
to : VicTus is name My

I know the answer but I want to know more ways to answer this. Programming language is Python 3. Answer in any way as you want. Give some tips to master Python.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution1:

```py
a = "My name is VicTus"
' '.join(reversed(a.split()))
```

The `split` function splits the string into a list according to its input separators (which are whitespaces by default).

The `reversed` function reverses the string (It doesn't actually reverse the list and only changes the order in which Python iterates through it).

The `join` function unifies the list into one string with elements separated by the specified string (space in this case).

### Solution2:

```py
a = "My name is VicTus"
' '.join(a.split()[::-1])
```

The `[::-1]` reverses the list. Indexing in Python works like this:

`LIST [ START : END : STEP ]`

When you don't define the `START` and the `END` they will be considered as the start and end of the string. If the step is negative, Python starts from the end of the string, which will reverse it.

These two solutions split the string with the default separator, all the whitespaces (`" \t\n\r\x0b\x0c"`). If you want to add them to your separators, what you can do:

### Solution3:

```py
import string

a = "My name is VicTus"
' '.join(reversed(a.split(string.whitespace + "Your own separators")))
```

Or use Regex:

### Solution4:

```py
import re

a = "My name is VicTus"
' '.join(reversed(re.findall(r'\w+', a)))
```

The `re.findall` function finds all the substrings in `a` that match the specified pattern in regex.

In this case, `"\w+"` means one or more alphanumeric characters.